# Should I centralize the covariates in a longitudinal mixed effects model with treatment-covariate interactions?

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, causality, treatment-effect

I have a randomized binary treatment $A$ assigned to individuals observed on outcome $Y$ on $m$ fixed measurement occasions $T$. There is a individual level covariate $X$ observed. Generally including $X$ in the model will improve efficiency of statistical inference, if $X$ is a predictor of $Y$.

Assume for a second that we only have one measurement occasion. Then we could estimate the treatment effect

$$\eta = E(Y(1)-Y(0))$$

where $Y(1),Y(0)$ are the potential outcomes, by the following linear regression model:

$$E(Y|A,X) = \beta_0 + \eta A + \beta_1 X + \beta_2 XA$$

where $\beta_2$ is the coefficient of the treatment-covariate interactions. However, this does not in general lead to the correct treatment effect because

$$E(Y(1)-Y(0)) = \sum_x [E(Y|A=1,X=x) - E(Y|A=0,X=x)] p(x)  \\
               = \sum_x [\eta + \beta_2 x] p(x) \\
               = \eta + \beta_2 E(X)$$

which holds under randomized treatment and some regularity conditions from causal inference, not relevant here.

As a consequence this model does not estimate the causal effect correctly unless we centralize $X$

$$E(Y|A,X) = \beta_0 + \eta A + \beta_1 (X-E(X)) + \beta_2 (X-E(X))A$$

This is e.g. noted by [Schafer and Kang](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/23652902_Average_Causal_Effects_From_Nonrandomized_Studies_A_Practical_Guide_and_Simulated_Example) (2008), equation 11.

**My question is:** *if instead I have more than one measurement occasion with a binary or continuous covariate $X$, should I then also centralize and how should this be done?*

Let's consider the mixed model with random intercept $u_{0i}$:

$$ Y_{it} = \gamma_{00} + \sum_{s=2}^m \gamma_{1t} T_{ist} + \eta A_i + \gamma_2 \tilde{X}_i + \gamma_3 A_i \tilde{X}_i  + u_{0i} + \epsilon_{it}$$

with individuals $i=1,...,n$ and $t=1,...m$ and the occasion indicator $T_{ist}$ is 1 if $s=t$ and 0 else. Now, how should $\tilde{X}$ be centralized? Furthermore, should anything in this regard be done to $T_{ist}$ which is also a covariate?